# Which is called first in the fragment, the lifecycle callbacks OR the interface

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, interface, android-lifecycle

Can anyone explains to me please the behaviour of this interface? I have a `mainActivity` that in it i instantiate an object from the interface called `ToggleInterface`, the `ToggleInterface` calls the method `toggle.onMQTTConnectionPressed();` in `displaySelectionLayout` method in the `case 0:` as shown below in the `code_2`.

at run time, when there is no connection to the server and, i click item number 1 then item number 0, i receive the `log_1` posted below. and if there is a connection and I click item number 1 then item number 0, i receive `log_2` posted below but, the `Log.d(TAG, "debug message");` never show up.

how come that, when i swtich to `fragment` in `case 0:` when there is no connection, the `@onMQTTConnectionPressed()` is called first then `onCreateView`, `onActivityCreated`, `onStart`, `onResume` and then, ***again****, `onMQTTConnectionPressed`

And

how come that, when i swtich to `fragment` in `case 0:` when there is connection, the `@onMQTTConnectionPressed()` is called first then `onCreateView`, `onActivityCreated`, `onStart`, `onResume` and then, ***again****, `onMQTTConnectionPressed` BUT, `Log.d(TAG, "debug message");` is never called  despite the `isModeViewVisible` is true.

**Note**:

```
`ModeViewVisible`: return the visibility state of the initial view, the one is wilbe returned from `onCretaeView`, or in other words, the `rootview` of the fragment.
```

**Code_1**:

```
@Override
public void onMQTTConnectionPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if ( (this.getMQTTAsynchClient() != null) && (this.getMQTTAsynchClient().isConnected()) ) {
        Log.d(TAG, "@onMQTTConnectionPressed(): client Connected");

        if (this.rootView == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "@onMQTTConnectionPressed(): rootView = null");
        }
        if (isModeViewVisible()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "@onMQTTConnectionPressed(): ModeViewVisible = true");
            hideModeViews();
            Log.d(TAG, "debug message");
            //showSubscriptionViews();
        }
        if (isConfigViewVisible()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "@onMQTTConnectionPressed(): ConfigViewVisible = true");
        }

        if (isSubViewVisible()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "@onMQTTConnectionPressed(): subViewVisible = true");
        }
        //showSubscriptionViews();

    } else {

        Log.d(TAG, "@onMQTTConnectionPressed(): client not Connected");

        if (isModeViewVisible()) {

        } else if (isConfigViewVisible()) {
            hideMQTTConfigViews();
            showModeView();
            Log.d(TAG, "@onMQTTConnectionPressed(): returned to ModeView from MQTTConfigView.");
        }
    }
}
```

**code_2**:

```
private void displaySelectionLayout(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Fragment fragment = null;
    boolean flag = false;

    switch (position) {

    case 0:
        //fragment = MQTT_Fragment;
        //flag = true;
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, MQTT_Fragment).commit();
        navDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true); 
        navDrawerListView.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navDrawerOptions[position]);
        navDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(navDrawerListView);
        toggle.onMQTTConnectionPressed();
        break;

    case 1:
        fragment = Eco_Fragment;

        Log.d(TAG, "@displaySelectionLayout: " + this.getNavDrawerArrayList().get(0).isOptionVisibile());
        break;

    case 2: fragment = Logger_Fragment;
        break;

    case 3: fragment = Exit_Fragment;
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
```

**isModeViewVisible**:

```
    private boolean isModeViewVisible() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if ( (rg_ConfigChoice != null) && (rg_ConfigChoice.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

**MainActivity**:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ItemVisibilityPasser {
....
....
private Fragment MQTT_Fragment = new MQTT_Fragment(); 
private Fragment Eco_Fragment = new Eco_Assistant_Fragment(); 
private Fragment Logger_Fragment = new Data_Logger_Fragment(); 
private Fragment Exit_Fragment = new Exit_Fragment(); 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    toggle =  (ToggleInterface) MQTT_Fragment; 
    initViews();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        displaySelectionLayout(0);
    }
}
```

**log_1**:

```
01-22 10:35:37.933: D/MQTT_Fragment(20534): @onMQTTConnectionPressed(): client not Connected
01-22 10:35:37.963: W/MQTT_Fragment(20534): @onCreateView()
01-22 10:35:37.963: W/MQTT_Fragment(20534): @onActivityCreated()
01-22 10:35:37.963: W/MQTT_Fragment(20534): @onStart()
01-22 10:35:37.963: W/MQTT_Fragment(20534): @onResume()
01-22 10:35:37.963: D/MQTT_Fragment(20534): @onResume(): NOT CONNECTED
01-22 10:35:37.963: D/MQTT_Fragment(20534): @onMQTTConnectionPressed(): ModeViewVisible = true

**Log_2**:

01-22 10:37:02.053: D/MQTT_Fragment(20534): @onMQTTConnectionPressed(): client Connected
01-22 10:37:02.083: W/MQTT_Fragment(20534): @onCreateView()
01-22 10:37:02.083: W/MQTT_Fragment(20534): @onActivityCreated()
01-22 10:37:02.093: W/MQTT_Fragment(20534): @onStart()
01-22 10:37:02.093: W/MQTT_Fragment(20534): @onResume()
01-22 10:37:02.093: D/MQTT_Fragment(20534): @onResume(): CONNECTED
01-22 10:37:02.093: D/MQTT_Fragment(20534): @onMQTTConnectionPressed(): ModeViewVisible = true
```

Comment: When is `MQTT_Fragment` created? Also please add the code of how `isModeViewVisible` works, a description is not enough.

Comment: @user3249477 i dded the code of the method required. MQTT_Fragment  is created when the user clicks the first item in the listView of a NavigatioDrawer.